# Show that $T_\infty=\{U : X-U \text{ is infinite or empty or all of $X$} \}$ is a topology on $X$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set. Show that the collection
$$T_\infty=\{U : X-U \text{ is infinite or empty or all of $X$} \}$$

is a topology on $X$.

Well $X-X=\emptyset$, so $X \in T_\infty$. And $X-\emptyset= X$ and therefore in $T_\infty$.

Let assume that $\{U_\alpha\}$ is indexed family of sets of $T_\alpha$ that are not empty or $X$. Than 
$$X-\cup U_\alpha =\cap X- U_\alpha$$ it seems strange to me that this intersection must be infinite. I don't know $(-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$ have a finite intersection. Maybe I oversee something.

Comment: Well every point of X is open in your $T_\infty$, that already implies the discrete topology in which every set is open....

Comment: Are you certain it says INfinite in the definition? Because if it said _finite_, then this would be the finite complement topology, a beloved counterexample of many wrong intuitions in intruductory topology. As it is now, this is not a topology in general, since $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$ would be open in $\Bbb R$, but not their union.

Comment: $T_{\alpha} \rightarrow T_{\infty}$?

Comment: @Arthur Oh, my teacher exactly asked for a counterexample, sorry guys :p, should I delete this question ?

Comment: @Kasper No, you shouldn't. Write an answer yourself, explaining that it was not supposed to be a topology, accept it and keep it up for posterity's sake.

Comment: @Arthur Done :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you have problems proving this, is because your statement is not true.

If $X$ is finite, there are no problems. You can check that in this case $X$ is the trivial topology.

But suppose that $X$ is infinite. Suppose that you can partition $X$ into three disjoint sets $X=X_1\cup X_2 \cup X_3$ where $X_1,X_2$ are infinite, and $X_3$ is finite. Now $X_1$ and $X_2$ have infinite complements, and so are open. But $X_1 \cup X_2$ has a finite complement ($X_3$) and therefore is not open. This contradicts the definition of a topology !

Comment: You can always do such partition :) not need to Suppose the existence of. In fact if X is infinite, in particular is not empty, so $x \in X$, call $X_3 =\{x \}$. Now consider $X\setminus \{ x \} = Y$. It is an infinite set, so in particular its cardinality is greater or equal the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$. If $|Y| = \mathbb{N}$ you can choose the preimage of the set of even number as $X_1$ and odd number as $X_2$. If it is greater than $\mathbb{N}$ in particular $Y$ contains a countable subset. take this subset and its complement in $Y$.

Comment: I only wanted to emphasize the universality of your affirmation :) (maybe it's an overkill to prove the existence of such partition but this kind of topology is so strictly related to the concept of (and property of) cardinality that it was "like called" such kind of approach ;)

Comment: @RicPed Cool, I was wondering that. I should have asked the question: Prove that $T_\infty$ is a topology when $X$ is finite, and that $T_\infty$ is not a topology when $X$ is infinite.